# change season in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  dataset like this

| Month | Season |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 | 4 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 11 | 4 |
| 12 | 1 |

Now I would like to change 1 to winter, 2 to spring, 3 to summer and 4  to autumn in the season column.

I was struggling.

I want this dataset after

| Month | Season |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | winter |
| 2 | winter |
| 3 | spring |
| 4 | spring |
| 5 | spring |
| 6 | summer |
| 7 | summer |
| 8 | summer |
| 9 | autumn |
| 10 | autumn |
| 11 | autumn |
| 12 | winter |

I gave the following code

```
df.replace({'Season' : { 1 : winter, 2 : spring, 3: summer, 4: autumn}})
```

But got an error

The error is could not find winter???

Comment: What have you tried?  That's trivially easy, either with 4 assignment statements or one use of `.apply`.

Comment: Or with `map` and a dict.

Comment: i used df.replace() but didn't work

Comment: Strings need enclosed in quotes, for starters?

Comment: But I didn't get the result I want with the quotes

Comment: @Jaime, added solution

Comment: Right, because you used `replace` incorrectly. When in doubt, you can consult the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest `apply` approach:

```
def month_to_season(row):
    if (row + 1) // 3 == 1:
        return 'spring'
    if (row + 1) // 3 == 2:
        return'summer'
    if (row + 1) // 3 == 3:
        return 'autumn'
    return 'winter'


df['Season'] = df['Month'].apply(month_to_season)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a dictionary for season
d={1:'winter', 2 : 'spring', 3 : 'summer', 4 : 'autumn'}

# map season value using dictionary
df['Season']=df['Season'].map(d)
df
```

```
Month   Season
0   1   winter
1   2   winter
2   3   spring
3   4   spring
4   5   spring
5   6   summer
6   7   summer
7   8   summer
8   9   autumn
9   10  autumn
10  11  autumn
11  12  winter
```

Alternately, for completeness sake. you can update your solution of using replace as follows (as others have commented here), which results in the same result

```
df.replace({'Season' : { 1 : 'winter', 2 : 'spring', 3: 'summer', 4: 'autumn'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the seasons like winter, summer etc in quotes. For example, `winter` becomes `"winter"`

The problem is that winter is treated as a variable, not a string.

This should help with the `winter not found error`.